# Stop Kafka Consumer after consuming the log end offset using reactor kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, reactor-kafka

I have a requirement where I will consume all message from a topic from the beginning to the latest message offset in the partition then stop the consumer from listening to the topic. I have created the following code snippet:

```
ReceiverOptions<String, byte[]> receiverOptions = this.receiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singleton( topicName ) )
          .addAssignListener( partitions -> {
              log.debug( "starting to {} offset", startOffset );
              partitions.forEach( element -> element.seekToBeginning() 
          )
          .addRevokeListener( partitions -> log.debug( "partition revoked = {}", partitions ) );

Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, byte[]>> fluxKafka = KafkaReceiver.create( receiverOptions ).receive();

disposable = fluxKafka.publishOn( Schedulers.fromExecutor( scheduledExecutor ) )
          .subscribe( record -> {

              log.debug( "received record [offset = {}, message = {}, timestamp = {}]", record.offset(),
                            new String( record.value() ), record.timestamp() );

              T message = avroDeserializer.deserialize( record.value() );

              Optional.ofNullable( onMessageHandler )
                            .ifPresent( handler -> handler.accept( message ) );

              record.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
          } );
```

I don't know what approach should I do.. I'm thinking of getting the current partition position() but I'm not sure if I should proceed with it..

Comment: Would you like to have more than one instance active within consumer group?

Comment: do you mean one consumer instance? the default implementation is for us to have one instance of consumer listen to a topic with 1 partition but there will be some instance where we will have multiple consumer in a single consumer group with multiple partitions (we will do it as 1 consumer per 1 partition)

Comment: Imho your code snippet is ok, you just need to add two things:
1. store in some singleton last offsets of topic and partition during consumer assignment, handle it in `addAssignListener` implementation.
2. then just invoke `close()` on consumer when  you process offset from point one.
Remember that it wouldn't be so simple if you want to process more than one partition within single consumer :(

Comment: I would also consider resign from Kafka auto partition assignment feature and set subscription using manual assignment to the specified partitions (using assignment(Collection<org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition> partitions) method), then seek to the beginning and then finally start consuming messages.

Comment: what method should I use to get the last message offset in the addAssignListener? I can only see viable option is the position e.g. element.position(); 

based on this https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/api/reactor/kafka/receiver/ReceiverPartition.html it Returns the offset of the next record that will be fetched from this topic partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, I'm not familiar with reactor so it took me a while, but the code below works as expected:

```java
public Disposable consumeMessages(TopicPartition topicPartition) {
        ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> options = receiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singleton(topicPartition.topic()))
                .addAssignListener(partitions -> partitions.forEach(ReceiverPartition::seekToBeginning));
        KafkaReceiver<Integer, String> kafkaReceiver = KafkaReceiver.create(options);
        return kafkaReceiver
                .receive()
                .flatMap(record -> kafkaReceiver.doOnConsumer(consumer -> consumer.endOffsets(Collections.singleton(topicPartition))).cache()
                        .map(topicPartitionToLastOffset -> Tuples.of(record, topicPartitionToLastOffset.get(topicPartition))))
                .takeUntil(recordAndLastOffset -> recordAndLastOffset.getT1().offset() >= (recordAndLastOffset.getT2()-1))
                .subscribe(record -> {
                    ReceiverOffset offset = record.getT1().receiverOffset();
                    System.out.printf("Received message: topic-partition=%s offset=%d key=%d value=%s\n",
                            offset.topicPartition(),
                            offset.offset(),
                            record.getT1().key(),
                            record.getT1().value());
                    offset.acknowledge();
                });
    }
```

Comment: thanks! do you think it's wise to add a doAfterTerminate pipeline then set a flag variable so that the caller thread will just check it and will know that the consumer is ready to be disposed (by calling .dispose()) or you have a better approach to this?

Comment: Ohhh sorry @RicoSanchoAbarro but as I mentioned I know something about Kafka but almost nothing about reactive programming 